# Should DialogFragments have their own ViewModel or should they use the ViewModel of their containing Fragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am new to android and i am not sure if it is a good practice to let DialogFragments use the ViewModel of their containing Fragment, or should it have a ViewModel of its own.

I am asking this since Google recommends that each Activity/Fragment has its own ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with the dialog having it's own ViewModel.  This would fall into the Single Responsibility Principle, where the Fragment only handles what's relevant to it and ditto for the `DialogFragment`. Try and keep them uncoupled.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle